# closure within v-for, attribute interpolation

Tags: vue.js

I have this basic setup

```
<div v-for="n in 4">
  <some-component @on-some-event="onSomeEvent(n)"></some-component>
</div>
```

the `on-some-event` is dispatched within `some-component`. but I need to know which of these components sent the message. with the setup above, only `n` is passed into the method. and the data that the event sends is nowhere.

I'd like to interpolate the function so that the method looks like this

```
onSomeEvent(n){
  return (obj)=>{
    console.log(`component ${n} sent ${obj}`);
  };
}
```

but wrapping `onSomeEvent` with `{{}}` throws a warning: `attribute interpolation is not allowed in Vue.js directives and special attributes.`

I could just pass the `n` index into the component but that seems less elegant because I may not have the ability to modify `some-component`

I am somewhat new to Vue, so perhaps I am missing some core functionality for this type of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div v-for="n in 4">
  <some-component @on-some-event="onSomeEvent | pass n"></some-component>
</div>

....
filters: {
   pass(handler, n) {
       return function() {
           handler()(n, ...arguments)
       }
   }
},
methods: {
   onSomeEvent() {
       console.log(...arguments)  
   }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2s6hqcy5/2/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't miss anything, the message is correct, in Vue, you won't be able to use interpolation like that.
http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Interpolations

However, you may want to change how you manage events and pass data between components. In your example, you can just bind the data like this:

```
<div v-for="n in 4">
    <some-component :n="n"></some-component>
</div>
```

In your component, declare the prop:

```
Vue.component('some-component', {
  props: ['n'],
  ...
```

Now, inside each component, you have the `n` available like any other property (http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props).

Then when dispatching your event, you can call it like this, with no need for a param:

```
onSomeEvent()
```

On the event itself, you can access the `n`:

```
console.log('Component' + this.n + ...)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/mjnjy1jt/